# What happens if future.get() is called after promise.set_value()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future, race-condition

I create a promise and future objects:

```
Promise<int> p = promise<int>(); 
Future<int> f = p.get_future();
```

I pass the promise to the background thread, which eventually calls `p.set_value(myInt)`.

In the main thread, I call `f.get()`.

What if `f.get()` is called **after** `p.set_value(myInt)` is called?

Would `f.get()` immediately return `myInt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation it calls [wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) - in order to wait for a result. According to that description in turn, it is stated that:

> Blocks until the result becomes available.

That seems to imply it should not block (even for a short while) if there is a result already. So except for some sanity checks, mutex handling or the like I would assume it to return immediately as per the description.

Do you have an actual issue or are you merely asking ?

Comment: It seemed like I had an issue, so I decided to ask. But that issue is now resolved.